# Asus N76VM backlight keyboard doesn't work

Tags: keyboard, hardware-failure, backlight

so i just bought an asus N76VM and the backlit doesn't work, i upgraded to win10 an re-installed all the drivers (atk package, keyboard filter...) and still not working, the keyboard doesnt light up on boot. 
Can someone help me?

Comment: Did you also tried to increase the backlit manually via the function key combination? fn + F4

Comment: Yeah sure, doesn't work

Comment: UUUUUUUUUUUUUUP